# Azure SQLManagementClient ResourceNotFound: The Uri doesn't match any specific service operation

Tags: azure

I'm trying to have an Azure SQL database programmatically exported to blob storage using the management libraries.

```
SqlManagementClient managementClient = new SqlManagementClient(credentials);
var exportParams = new DacExportParameters()
{
    BlobCredentials = new DacExportParameters.BlobCredentialsParameter()
    {

        StorageAccessKey = tenant.StorageKey,
        Uri = new Uri(String.Format(@"https://" + tenant.StorageName + ".blob.core.windows.net/updatebackups/{0}.bacpac", tenant.DBName + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()))
    },
    ConnectionInfo = new DacExportParameters.ConnectionInfoParameter()
    {
        ServerName = tenant.DBServer,
        DatabaseName = tenant.DBName,
        UserName = tenant.DBUserName,
        Password = tenant.DBPassword
    }
};

var exportResult = managementClient.Dac.Export(tenant.DBServer, exportParams);
```

Unfortunately I'm getting a slightly vague error:

> ResourceNotFound: The Uri doesn't match any specific service operation.

I've checked:

- The subscription ID
- The server name (it's in the format *.database.windows.net)
- The storage name (and the container exists if that matters)

All seem correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out despite the fact that both of the variables are called `ServerName`, one of them requires a full path, and the other requires just the name.

Changing the stored value to the short name and running this code fixed it:

```
SqlManagementClient managementClient = new SqlManagementClient(credentials);
var exportParams = new DacExportParameters()
{
    BlobCredentials = new DacExportParameters.BlobCredentialsParameter()
    {

        StorageAccessKey = tenant.StorageKey,
        Uri = new Uri(String.Format(@"https://" + tenant.StorageName + ".blob.core.windows.net/updatebackups/{0}.bacpac", tenant.DBName + "_" + DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()))
    },
    ConnectionInfo = new DacExportParameters.ConnectionInfoParameter()
    {
        ServerName = tenant.DBServer + ".database.windows.net",
        DatabaseName = tenant.DBName,
        UserName = tenant.DBUserName,
        Password = tenant.DBPassword
    }
};

var exportResult = managementClient.Dac.Export(tenant.DBServer, exportParams);
```

Note the `+ ".database.windows.net"`

Comment: Thanks for this.  I would have never figured out that difference.